# Moving the Shipping Calculation to the Totals Block

Tags: magento

We have a requirement to move the shipping calculation block to the totals block.

[image: example]

Basically we have 2 options when the cart page loads up:

1) When shipping is set, present the shipping rate normally.
2) When shipping is not set, present the html and form to post a shipping request.

Issue is, the shipping block inside the totals block is not rendered when there is no shipping price so we moved the html of the shipping calculation inside the totals block. Problem with that is, that the sales tax is shown BEFORE the shipping which obviously is incorrect.

As far as I see it, the only option we have is to create a new total block, for instance "calculate_shipping" and call it only when there is no shipping rate. This total block will have no real "total" value but just bare HTML with the form post.

Your thoughts and suggestions are appreciated. I'm hoping there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of modules out there that might help:

http://www.rapidcommerce.eu/blog/2012/04/allways-show-shipping-costs-in-magento/

and

https://github.com/integer-net/Autoshipping